# Is there a way not to show a window for a SwiftUI-lifecycle macOS app?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm looking to not show a window for a SwiftUI application on macOS. The app uses SwiftUI's application lifecycle and only runs in the status bar. Showing a window on start up is unnecessary. I'm unsure however how to get around the `WindowGroup`. There's no such a thing as an `EmptyScene` and putting an `EmptyView` inside the `WindowGroup` of course creates an empty window.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I basically only need the app delegate. I'm guessing using the default AppKit lifecycle makes more sense, but if there is a way to use SwiftUI's lifecycle, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 24):

In your AppDelegate, do the following in your applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    // Close main app window
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.close()
    }
    
    // Code continues here...
}
```

For example:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover = NSPopover.init()
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Close main app window
        if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
            window.close()
        }
        
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the contents
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Set the SwiftUI's ContentView to the Popover's ContentViewController
        popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 160, height: 160)
        popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        
        // Create the Status Bar Item with the above Popover
        statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Thank you. You made my day

Comment: This seams to be the only working workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found that my popovers content loads way slower using this on first run. I changed it to I  window.orderOut(self). which seems to allow quicker loading of the content

Answer (score 10):

> The app uses ***SwiftUI's application lifecycle*** and ***only runs in the status bar***.

Use a [`MenuBarExtra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextra)
scene to render a persistent control in the system menu bar with the native SwiftUI lifecycle. (Xcode 14.2, macOS Ventura)

```swift
@main
struct MyStatubarMenuApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        // -- no WindowGroup required --
        // -- no AppDelegate needed --
        MenuBarExtra { 
            Text("Hello Status Bar Menu!")
            MyCustomSubmenu()
            Divider()
            Button("Quit") { NSApp.terminate(nil) }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "bolt.fill")
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Add and set `Application is agent = YES` in `Info.plist` for the app icon to *not show* on the dock.
- `systemName:` SF Symbols will automatically toggle appearance when the `System Settings…` > `Appearance` is changed.
- `@Environment(\.colorScheme)` [does not currently update at the App/Scene level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76776390/detect-macos-system-dark-light-apperance-at-the-swiftui-app-scene-level-for-use)

Comment: I found this page using the same approach with screenshots: https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-menu-bar-app/

Answer (score 8):

If you app has settings (who doesn't?), you can do like this:

```swift
@main
struct TheApp: App {
  @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

  var body: some Scene {
    Settings {
      SettingsView()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just `Settings {}` works if you don't want to show anything.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var body: some Scene {
  WindowGroup {
    ZStack {
      EmptyView()
    }
    .hidden()
  }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately also creates an empty window :/

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Have updated, try this.

Comment: The Window menu will still show those windows even though none are visible.

Comment: Add "Application is agent = YES" in Info.plist with this and it will work. Tnx!

Comment: This is a very dangerous solution, with Side Effects.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361896/swiftui-menubar-app-with-assertion-on-main

Answer (score 0):

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup{
        EmptyView()
            .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            .hidden()
    }
    .windowResizability(.contentSize)
}
```

the windowResizability(_:) is available on macOS 13+