# SwiftUI MenuBar App with Assertion on @main

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, appdelegate, menubar

I have a SwiftUI Menu Bar App with no visible Windows on startup, except an entry in the Menu Bar with a Button showing a View on click.

This works great, but sporadically, the App throws an assertion and the **MenuBar Button is not added**, though its impossible to click it.

Here is what **does not** solve the issue:

- Cleaning Build + Derived Data
- Reboots

Code in AppDelegate (needed for the MenuBar)

```swift
@main // Assertion thrown here
struct MenuBarApp: App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            // This surpresses opening an empty Window on launch
            ZStack{
                EmptyView()
            }.hidden() // removing .hidden() sometimes make the assertion go away, sometimes having .hidden() here triggers it

            // Sometimes, a second ZStack makes the assertion dissappear, sometimes it triggers it.
        }
    }
}
```

The assertion reads:

> 2022-05-24 12:58:06.263464+0200 MenuBar[7119:96419] *** Assertion failure in void _NSWindowSetFrameIvar(NSWindow *, NSRect)(), NSWindow.m:935

> 2022-05-24 13:04:40.477258+0200 MenuBar[7119:96419] Invalid parameter not satisfying: <SwiftUI.SwiftUIWindow: 0x159e63780>. "frame=CGRectContainsRect(CGRectMake((CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MAX - (CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MAX - (CGFloat)INT_MIN), frame)"

On other machines the build and launch of the same Code runs perfectly fine.

`func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification)` is not getting called in the assert case

`macOS 12.4, M1 Max, XCode 13.3.1`

Comment: Interesting Point from @vidian, before he deleted his answer.

Comment: I deleted the answer because the statement *I have a SwiftUI Menu Bar App with no Windows* is a bit misleading. It's a window which causes the error.

Comment: Well, got your point, but it is the setup above ( with no windows ) that triggers the assertion. It also happens with more Window Groups, but i wanted to make it as short as possible to understand the issue.

Nevertheless i think your hint goes into the right direction, removing the Empty WindowGroup and just working with the othersm settings ect. helped, so i assume that Empty WindowGroup is part of the problem. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

> Code in AppDelegate (needed for the MenuBar)

The `AppDelegate` is no longer needed with the release of [`MenuBarExtra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextra) as of Xcode 14.2, macOS 13 Ventura. A `MenuBarExtra` scene renders a persistent control in the system menu bar with the native SwiftUI lifecycle.

```swift
@main
struct MyStatubarMenuApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        // -- no WindowGroup required --
        // -- no AppDelegate needed --
        MenuBarExtra("") { 
            Text("Hello Status Bar Menu!")
        }
    }
}
```