# Detect macOS system Dark/Light apperance at the SwiftUI App/Scene level (for use with MenuBarExtra)?

Tags: swift, swiftui, darkmode, menubarextra

**How to detect, if possible, the macOS system Dark/Light apperance at the SwiftUI App/Scene level? This particular case is for use with `MenuBarExtra`.**

In general, one might expect the following to work:

```swift
@main
struct ModeCheckApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme

        MenuBarExtra {
            Text(colorScheme == .dark ? "Dark" : "Light")
            Button("Print ColorScheme") { 
                print("colorScheme is '\(colorScheme)'")
            }
        } label: { 
            Image(colorScheme == .light ? "ImageA" : "ImageB")
        }
    }
}
```

The above approach runs, but never updates:

> Runtime Warning: "Accessing Environment's value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update."

Alternately, one might expect an xcasset Image with all of `Any, Light, Dark` images to automagically be selected. However, the approach only provides the `Light` appearance image -- same as the prior approach.

```swift
            Image("ImageC")
```

[image]

Somehow, the `systemName:` image will automatically change with the macOS appearance settings:

```swift
            Image(systemName: "questionmark")
```

Note, this question scope is for:

1. `macOS` at the `App` `Scene` level which can be used with a standalone `MenuBarExtra` utility.
2. does not use non-applicable approach, e.g. a `View` level solution which is found in other StackOverflow questions… and which, does not work with the current Xcode 14.3.
3. can use developer provided images i.e. not the system provided images. Although, perhaps there is something the system images have that developer images can replicate??